# replace text on your page php something like element.innerhtml

Tags: php

hello i have been searching for some php code that is something like element.innerHTML in javascript but i can't find it. i need it for some code that for example goes from 1-60 in 60 seconds
but if i do that with echo it just places everything under each other and that should not happen. i need something that just replaces the text. i also don't want to reload my page every second and i don't have the ability to write to files ( i can read them). and please don't tell me that i should do it in javascript.
so can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You should do that in JavaScript

Comment: You say that 1) you don't want to reload the page and 2) you don't want to use javascript. If both of those are true, then you won't be able to solve your problem without violating one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP to spit out javascript that does the replacing. There won't be a pure PHP solution to this since PHP is server-side and doesn't have access to the rendering of the page on the client side.

Suppose the text you need to change is in a `<div>` tag named 'replaceMe'. You will want to use the ob_flush() functions in PHP to force out the javascript at the time you need it to display. The PHP to initialize that is

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
```

Then, each time you need to update, you have something like this in your PHP code that adds to the body of the page:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">';
echo "document.getElementById('replaceMe').innerHTML = 'Text for this iteration';";
echo '</script>';
flush(); ob_flush();
```

Of course if you want to make it easier for yourself, you can make a PHP function to print all this out given an argument containing the text to replace.

Then at the end you need to have

```
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: If you're going to emit javascript anyhow, there isn't any great value in using output buffering to emit scripts intermittently.

Comment: When in the body, the idea is that those scripts will get executed on emission.

Comment: But it's heavy-handed and emits a bunch of unnecessary bytes of script text to the client. You can fulfill his requirement in pure javascript with ridiculous ease.

Comment: I understand that and if I had it my way I would do it purely in javascript as well. But I can also understand that there could be situations where that's not possible - for example suppose you want to have a progress bar for a function that executes in PHP. How would you use javascript for that?

For that particular problem, you can solve it via CSS and printing out <div>'s but the OP said he didn't want to deal with multiple elements on top of each other and didn't want/couldn't have a pure Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

to replace some text try str_replace http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php
or case insensitive str_ireplace

Comment: that is just to replace a string in a variable not on your page

Comment: ok so if i get you right, you want to change content on a page you dont have access to?